# Unable to access property using get_json_object in Hive

Tags: hive

#### Brief Intro

Data that I'm trying to extract values from (have undergone anonymization):

```
requestheader: {
    "Accept":"*/*",
    "X-U-F":"0"
}
```

When I query value of 'Accept' using :

```
SELECT get_json_object(requestheader, '$.Accept')
FROM *
WHERE *
```

It gave '*/*' as expected.

While I tried to extract value of 'X-U-F' using the same way:

```
SELECT get_json_object(requestheader, '$.X-U-F')
...
```

I got NULL

If my memory serves right, dashes should not be the obstacle to this problem.(Can it be ?)

How can I get the value of 'X-U-F' ?